apostrophe-like character appears in DataFrame as 'â\x80\x99'
I am reading from SQL using sqlalchemy
q = """select * from table_name"""
data = pd.read_sql_query(q,con)

It appears ok when I view the results on screen

but when I assign it to a variable and write back to sql, it comes odd looking
string_oi = data.iloc[0,8]
df = pd.DataFrame({'test':[string_oi]})
df.to_sql(
    name= 'tableTest',
    con = con,
    if_exists='replace',
    index = False
)
con.commit()    


When I define the string directly, it goes to SQL correctly
string_oi = 'Tylerâs way'


Examining the string when read from sql, the accent is encoded as â\x80\x99, ie
'Tylerâ\x80\x99s way'

How can I save/convert it so that strings are read correctly, which will then be ok when saving back to SQL? Presumably, this will happen with other special characters when reading the SQL table, and I would like to take care of this in a single step

What do you mean by "apostrophe"? I don't see an apostrophe. Do you mean the accent mark over the a?

updated questions @DanGetz, it is the accent, not apostrophe

When you say "reading from SQL" do you mean "reading from Microsoft SQL Server"?

yes. using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

What versions of Python, pandas, SQLAlchemy, and pyodbc are you using? After calling .to_sql(), what is the data type of the tableTest.test column? Is it varchar(max) ?

And if the test column is nvarchar, what is the actual SQL statement that df.to_sql produces? I'll bet it does INSERT ... VALUES('Tylerâs way') instead of INSERT ... VALUES(N'Tylerâs way'). The N is incredibly important, but it's one of the reasons why ORMs and other magic programs that write SQL for you (and hide it from you) can make development harder. Also, where is the code that does Examining the string when read from sql? Perhaps that is what is encoding those extra characters before displaying it?

Also, after you do string_oi = data.iloc[0,8], what do type(string_oi) and repr(string_oi) return?

Python 3.11.4, pandas '2.0.3', sqlalchemy '2.0.18', type(string_oi) : <class 'str'>, repr(string_oi) : "'Tylerâ\\x80\\x99s way'", pyodbc '4.0.39'

according to https://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/HTMLandASCIItableC1.html, \x80 and \x99 are control characters, and not printable.
using
[i.replace('\x80','').replace('\x99','') for i in data.column]

works to remove, and when writing back to SQL poses no problem


This is a classic case of Mojibake.
In the source from which the data DataFrame was created, the original text was not "Tylerâs way", it was "Tyler’s way", where the apostrophe-looking character is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK (U+2019). That character is UTF-8 encoded as \xe2\x80\x99, and the process that created the data DataFrame mangled it into Tylerâ\x80\x99s way by decoding the UTF-8 bytes as latin1.
>>> "Tyler’s way".encode("utf-8")
b'Tyler\xe2\x80\x99s way'
>>> "Tyler’s way".encode("utf-8").decode("latin1")
'Tylerâ\x80\x99s way'

The best solution would be to fix the process that creates the data DataFrame so that it correctly handles Unicode text.
